# Failsafe way to access variable with php (7) in eloquent model (applies generally really)

Tags: php, eloquent, php-7

what I want to do is this

```
if($cause->cause_tags->where('tag_id', $tag->id)->first() ?? false){
//do stuff
}
```

this, fails with `undefined $cause` even though using `??` operator

What i am certainly **NOT** willing to do is this

```
    if(isset($cause) && isset($cause->cause_tags) && isset($cause->cause_tags->where('tag_id', $tag->id)) 
//this is dark middle age
```

is there no cleaner, more readable way to do this very very basic thing?

Comment: Why not `$cause ? $cause->cause_tags->first() : false`?

Comment: @Jamesking56 `$cause ? $cause->cause_tags->first() : false` will throw a notice and is considered bad (therefore in a laravel context, it actually throws an exception)

Answer (score 0):

The PHP [Null Coalescing Operator (`??`)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce) combines two operands into an expression. The value of the new expression is the value of the first operand if it is not `NULL`, otherwise its value is the value of the second operand (no matter if it is `NULL` or not).

The first operand in your expression is:

```
$cause->cause_tags->where('tag_id', $tag->id)->first()
```

which is itself a big expression.

This complete expression is evaluated before `??` get any chance to check its value. And `??` does know and doesn't care about the pieces of this expression, only about it final value.

In order to successfully evaluate the subexpression, `$cause` should be an object that has the `$cause_tags` property and this property should be an object of a class that has the `where()` method (that returns another object that has the `first()` method).

I hope your code meets all these conditions and the only uncertainty it has is about the value of `$cause` (`NULL` or an object).

Your check should be:

```
if (isset($cause) && ($cause->cause_tags->where('tag_id', $tag->id)->first() ?? false)) {
    //do stuff
}
```

You can replace `isset($cause)` with `$cause !== NULL` or simply with `$cause`. These tests are [equivalent](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisons).

You can, as well, get rid of the `??` operator because in this `if` statement it only clutters the code, it doesn't add any value to it. `NULL` evaluates as `FALSE` in boolean context anyway.

If at the point where this code runs you are not sure about the value of `$cause->cause_tags` you can test for its value before calling `where()` on it:

```
if ($cause && $cause->cause_tags && 
    $cause->cause_tags->where('tag_id', $tag->id)->first()) {
    // do stuff
}
```

A better (and OOP) way to do it is to encapsulate the checking of `$cause_tags` and the call to `where()` and `first()` into a method of the class of object `$cause`:

```
class Cause {
    protected $cause_tags;

    public getFirstTag($tagId)
    {
        return $this->cause_tags->where('tag_id', $tagId)->first();
    }
}
```

and the client code now should look like:

```
// assuming somewhere in the code above $cause is initialized as:
// $cause = new Cause();

if ($cause && $cause->getFirstTag($tag->id)) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

In the constructor of class `Cause` make sure you initialize `$cause_tags` with an object of the correct type and, if you need to modify `$cause_tags` for some reason, it is always an object of the correct type.

Comment: using `??` is not equivalent to not using it, as, note undefined `$a` : `$b = $a ?: 'not a';` will throw a notice. `if($a)` with undefined `$a` whereas `if($a ?? false)` will not throw a notice and is more readable, at least to me, than `if(isset($a) && $a)` it just requires less thinking. Now such a long answer for something so simple as : if this does not exist or work, return false. Seems a bit overkill, what do you think?

Comment: You are right about the notice, in the general case. My answer was specific to the piece of code you posted. `$a` in the posted code is a value returned by a function. There is no way `$a` is undefined in this case. And the last piece of code in my answer is perfectly safe assuming you initialize `$cause` either with `NULL` or with an object of the correct type. Because you should always initialize a variable before using it. It's a simple rule of writing clean code that ensures you don't have unpleasant surprises later and drops the need to use `isset()` again and again. Try it.